# Adding 1/n^2+1/(n+1)^2+... in a loop

Tags: c#, loops

I'm quite new to programming so this shouldn't be a problem to most of you. I'm supposed to write a program which sums 1/n^2 (n being consecutive natural numbers) while elements are bigger than constant eps=0,001. I wrote a piece of code and tried to edit it but I'm still stuck in an infinite loop in which I just get consecutive numbers, but it's quite obvious the sum should be between 1 and 2. I'd be more than grateful if anyone could show me what it is that I'm doing wrong.

```
namespace program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const double eps=0.001;
            int n=1;
            double x;
            x = 1 / (n * n);
            double sum=x;
            while (x > eps)
            {
                n++;
                sum = sum + x;
                Console.WriteLine(sum);
            }
            Console.Write("\nSum: {0}.", sum);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `x` is not a function of `n`, it's just a variable. It doesn't change in the loop.

Comment: Ok. but could you give me some hints on how to edit it?

Answer (score 1):

You never recalculate the value of x, so the while condition never becomes false. If you move the assignment inside, your code won't loop forever.

```
const double eps=0.001;
int n=1;
double x;

double sum=x;
while (true)
{
    x = 1.0 / (n * n);
    if (x < eps) {
        break;
    }
    n++;
    sum = sum + x;
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
Console.Write("\nSum: {0}.", sum);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things. First of all

```
1 / (n * n)
```

is an integer expression and is always either `0` or `1`. You need to make it a floating point expression like this:

```
1.0 / (n * n)
```

And then you need to update `x` inside the loop rather than assigning to `x` once and once only.

Perhaps like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const double eps = 0.001;
    int n = 1;
    double x = 1.0 / (n * n);
    double sum = 0.0;
    while (x > eps)
    {
        sum += x;
        n++;
        x = 1.0 / (n*n);
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    };
    Console.Write("\nSum: {0}", sum);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The downside of this is that the expression for `x` is written twice. So a better way is like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const double eps = 0.001;
    int n = 1;
    double sum = 0.0;
    while (true)
    {
        double x = 1.0 / (n * n);
        if (x <= eps)
            break;

        sum += x;
        n++;
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    };
    Console.Write("\nSum: {0}", sum);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I think this will add one more term than desired to sum.

Comment: @babbage makes a good point. I'll let you work out how to terminate the loop. I think I've covered the fundamental issues and I'm sure you can do the rest.

Comment: Now it says I use an unassigned variable x just before the do while loop, but ok, I'll try to work it out on my own. I think I'm a step further. Thanks

Comment: Not in my code! I'm sure you can sort the detail out. Please don't give up so easily.

Comment: I made it a do while to avoid writing expression for x twice. Alternative is while (true) with termination test inside the loop using break.